# PowerShell Function return value and further use of returned Variable

Tags: function, powershell, csv

I don't get how the functions works in PowerShell. I tried it out a bit like C++ or C# but those languages I last tried out 7 years ago.

So as I try to work with the functions I have this function:

```
function whichcsv(){
    $location = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $location.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
    $location.filter = "CSV (*.csv)| *.csv"
    $location.ShowDialog()
    write-host $location.FileName "in Function"    
}
```

which determines the location of the csv that is loaded afterwards but as soon as I try to load the variable `$location` outside of the function it's NULL

With the `write-host` statement you can see it has the full path of the file.

As soon as I try to load it outside the function right after the code it won't work as its says its NULL

```
...
    #Select which CSV
    whichcsv
...
    $CSV = Import-Csv -Path $location.FileName -UseCulture
    $y = $CSV | Select Inventarnummer
    $Filter = "Inventarnummer"
```

I tried to set my code in a `int main(void)` like in C-languages but I don't know how to handle this as well as there it would have been on the same scoope so it should have worked so but somehow it doesn't works as then I only get all in the console prompt but nothing ever happens

**Full code** for repro

```
#Importend:
#This is Work in Progress and not completed work.

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing

#Function Assembling

Function SaveWorkingdestination ()
{
    $Saveworking = New-Object -Typename System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
    $Saveworking.filter = "CSV (*.csv)| *.csv"
    $Saveworking.ShowDialog()

    return $Saveworking
}

function Savefaileddestination ()
{
    $Savefailed = New-Object -Typename System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
    $Savefailed.filter = "CSV (*.csv)| *.csv"
    $Savefailed.ShowDialog()

    return $Savefailed
}


function Compare ($location)
{
    #work in progress   
    $CSV1 = Import-Csv -Path $location.FileName -UseCulture
    $CSV2 = Import-Csv -Path $location.FileName -UseCulture
    Compare-Object $CSV1 $CSV2 -property WhichColumn -IncludeEqual

    return comparedfilename

}


function whichcsv(){

    $location = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $location.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
    $location.filter = "CSV (*.csv)| *.csv"
    $location.ShowDialog()
    write-host $location.FileName "in Funktion"

}

function Checktrough ($y , $Filter,$Saveworking,$Savefailed)
{
    foreach($n in $y)
    {
        try {
            $Computer = [system.net.dns]::resolve($n.$Filter) | Select HostName,AddressList 
            $IP = ($Computer.AddressList).IPAddressToString
            Write-Host $n.$Filter $IP
            New-Object PSObject -Property @{IPAddress=$IP; Name=$n.$Filter} | Export-Csv $Saveworking.FileName -NoTypeInformation -Append
        } catch {
            Write-Host "$($n.$Filter) is unreachable."
            New-Object PSObject -Property @{Name=$n.$Filter} | Export-Csv $Savefailed.FileName -NoTypeInformation -Append
        }
    }
}

#int main (void)  #doesnt working so far
#{

    #Select which option Form

    $form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
    $form.Text = "CSV Liste"
    $form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,300) 
    $form.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

    $OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(75,195)
    $OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
    $OKButton.Text = "OK"
    $OKButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK
    $form.AcceptButton = $OKButton
    $form.Controls.Add($OKButton)

    $CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,195)
    $CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
    $CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
    $CancelButton.DialogResult = [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::Cancel
    $form.CancelButton = $CancelButton
    $form.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

    $label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $label.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,20) 
    $label.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
    $label.Text = "Welche CSV Liste soll geladen werden:"
    $form.Controls.Add($label) 

    $listBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListBox 
    $listBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10,40) 
    $listBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
    $listBox.Height = 150

    [void] $listBox.Items.Add("AS400 Computer")
    [void] $listBox.Items.Add("AS400 Personalstamm")
    [void] $listBox.Items.Add("ADComputer")
    [void] $listBox.Items.Add("ADBenutzer")

    #Formclosed

    $form.Controls.Add($listBox) 

    $form.Topmost = $True

    $result = $form.ShowDialog()


    if ($result -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK)
    {

        #Select which CSV
        whichcsv
    
        $x = $listBox.SelectedItem

        switch ($x)
        {
            #Option 1 
            "AS400 Computer"
            {
                $CSV = Import-Csv -Path $location.FileName -UseCulture
                $y = $CSV | Select Inventarnummer
                $Filter = "Inventarnummer"
                #SaveWorkingdestination($Saveworking)
                #Export-Csv $Saveworking.FileName -NoTypeInformation -Append
            }

            #Option 2
            "AS400 Personalstamm" 
            {
                #not implemented yet
                $y = $CSV | Select SpaltennameBzwFilter
                $Filter = "Spaltennamme bzw Filter"
            }

            #Option 3
            "ADComputer" 
            {
                $CSV = Import-Csv -Path $location.FileName -Delimiter ',' 
                $y = $CSV | Select Name
                $Filter = "Name"
                SaveWorkingdestination
                Savefaileddestination
                Checktrough
            }

            #Option 4
            "ADBenutzer" 
            {
                #not implemented yet
                $y = $CSV | Select SpaltennameBzwFilter
                $Filter = "Spaltenname bzw Filter"
            }  
        }
    }
#}
```

Maybe someone knows how to help me eather with getting the common code in something like the int main (void) from c languages or how to get a proper return from the functions... if there are still unclearitys i will clearly answer them and edit to get this working

edit: with script part it works perfectly fine so far, but now is there a format question to get some more structure in it. or is it common to have no wrap around in powershell scripts like you have in c languages with the

```
int main (void)
{
    ...
    code
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your example:

```
function whichcsv(){
    $location = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $location.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
    $location.filter = "CSV (*.csv)| *.csv"
    $location.ShowDialog()
    write-host $location.FileName "in Function"    
}
```

`$location`, as assigned in the function body, is *local* to the function's scope. In PowerShell you can *read* variables from a parent scope, but writing to a variable creates a local copy by default, not persisted in the caller's scope.

What you want to do is `return` it's value from the scope, just like you would in a C-like language.

The caveat in PowerShell is that *any* value expression inside the function body that outputs anything will "bubble up" to the caller, not just the argument to `return`. So if you have statements inside the function body that return any value, make sure you capture or suppress that output:

```
function whichcsv(){
    $location = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $location.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
    $location.filter = "CSV (*.csv)| *.csv"
    [void]$location.ShowDialog() # <-- ShowDialog() returns a DialogResult, suppress it
    return $location.FileName # return the filename property value    
}
```

Then in the calling scope:

```
$CsvPath = whichcsv
```

`$CsvPath` will now contain the value of `$location.Filename` after the function returns

---

For more information about variable scoping in PowerShell, see the [`about_Scopes` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes)
For more information about the behavior of `return`, see the [`about_Return` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return)
For more information about the *reason* for this behavior in the first place, look into [pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines)

Comment: yeah its kinda confusing with those scopes in powershell when you first dont know about it and try to handle it like in c languages and so on... is there a ease and short explantion of those scopes from powershell? and if not to much for a question is there a wrap up like in c languages with the int main (void){}

Comment: @Kevin Yeah, jumping into a fundamentally different programming environment with a similar syntax can be quite confusing :-) Look at the example in my code (the second block) - `[void](statement or expression in here)` is an easy way to suppress output. For scopes, have a look at [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes)

Comment: allright its quite a lot of info to get into it but its a nice docu and i will work with it till i got the clue completly still one structre question open if there is a wrap up in scripting like in the c language or does the code "hang free", if i'm not wrong this would make a scope shift right? so now the free code is in local or whatever and then it would be in the "same scope" like the functions or am i wrong here?

Comment: No, it won't "shift scopes", it'll only swallow output

Answer (score 2):

You may have to use `$script`to change the scope level in which the variable can be used. To make the variable available outside the function do something like:

```
function whichcsv(){
    $location = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $location.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
    $location.filter = "CSV (*.csv)| *.csv"
    $location.ShowDialog()
    $script:locationfilename = $location.FileName
}

write-host "$($locationfilename) in Function"
```

Comment: ok this works out thank you, can i shorten the $script:locationfilename = $location.filename to something like $script:Fnp = $location.filename ?

Comment: Yeah  that works too... you can use anything you like you pretty much throwing `script`at the front of your variable.

Answer (score 0):

you have to return the object to the main program.

```
function whichcsv(){

$location = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
$location.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
$location.filter = "CSV (*.csv)| *.csv"
$location.ShowDialog()
return $location.FileName  

}

$path= whichcsv
write-host $path
```